# Web Map is not displayed in Openlayers with no errors

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to display a map from a geojson file. Below are my codes. The map didn't show and there were no errors in the console.

```
  var urlModev ='maps/StaRita.geojson';

  var styles = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 3
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'orange'
        })
      }),
      geometry: function(feature) {
        // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
        return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
      }
    })
  ];


        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: urlModev,
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                style: styles
            })
        }); 

        var EPSG ='EPSG:4326';

        var projection = ol.proj.get(EPSG);


              var map = new ol.Map({
                layers: [vectorLayer
                ],
                target: 'map',
            renderer: 'canvas',
                controls: ol.control.defaults({
                  attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                    collapsible: false
                  })
                }),
                view: new ol.View({
                projection:projection,
                  center: [19948.84, 19955.93],
                  zoom: 1
                })
              });
```

Comment: To help debug always check the request actual made to the server, and try it in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set up your map to use EPSG:4326 but then asked OpenLayers to display a map centred on `(19948.84, 19955.93)` which is out of range for a Lat/Lon map. So your data probably is being drawn just very small and a long way away from your map.